# LINQ query help please. Selecting most recent record for each FK

Tags: sql, linq

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```
Id     CheckboxId     Selected     DateCreated
1      1              1            1/1/2010
2      2              1            1/2/2010
3      1              0            1/3/2010
4      3              1            1/4/2010
5      3              0            1/5/2010
```

CheckboxId is a FK and the table is just a history of when the boxes are checked or unchecked.

What I want to get is the most recent record for each CheckboxId. In the case of my demo table I want rows 2, 3, and 5. How would you accomplish this? Also I'm sure this is as easy as a "where" at the beginning of the query but if it could also be modified to only get records before a specified date that would be fantastic.

I'm having trouble figuring out how I would write a query to do this in SQL and it's making a link query impossible. I'm sure it has to be a selection from a sub query of distinct checkboxIds coupled with a group by or something but my SQL just isn't that great.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
var results = (from x in context
       group x by x.CheckboxID into g
       select new
       {
           CheckboxID = g.Key,
           MaxItem = g.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault()
       });
```

Then you can do:

```
foreach (var x in results)
    x.MaxItem.Selected //...etc.
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll play with it tomorrow and see what I can do.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. I wrote it in the other LINQ syntax because I like it better. So my final query ended up being: var myItems = context.Source.Where(x => x.DateCreated < historyDate).GroupBy(x => x.CheckboxId).Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault()) This also returns my "Source" items instead of an anonymous data type which seems better to me for no good reason I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get the most recent entries per `CheckBoxId`, then join to that table to get the rest of the results:

```
;with CheckBoxRecent as (
    select
        CheckBoxId
       ,max(DateCreated) as MostRecentDate
    from
        CheckBoxData T
    where
        T.DateCreated < @SpecifiedDate
    group by
        CheckBoxId
)
select
    T1.*
from
    CheckBoxData T1
inner join
    CheckBoxRecent T2 on T1.CheckBoxId = T2.CheckBoxId
        and T1.DateCreated = T2.MostRecentDate
order by
    CheckBoxId
```

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to convert to LINQ :)

Comment: This is good but not quite what I need. I need the actual rows, specifically I need the Selected column. I'm trying to look back into the history at the specified date and see which checkboxeId's had Selected=1.

Comment: DanDan! Ok I don't have my table set up yet but I believe this query now is what I need in SQL. Now to figure out how to do that in LINQ.

Comment: @William - please see my first answer it should get you pretty close to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment you want checkboxes selected on a specified date

```
var results = db.CheckBoxHistory.Where(cbh => cbh.Selected == 1 && cbh.DateCreated.Date == DateSpecified)
```

will get you those results, if you want to limit it to the latest by `CheckboxId` just add this

```
.GroupBy(cbh => cbh.CheckboxId)
```

you could loop the results and grab the latest for each checkboxid like so

```
foreach(var result in results) {
    var latest = result.OrderByDescending(cbh => cbh.DateCreated).FirstOrDefault();
    //latest has all fields in the checkboxhistory table
}
```

Comment: I don't think you quite understand my need. I need the most recent history record for each checkbox ID. It can't be simply the most recent one with selected=1 because that would give me inaccurate data. Look at my table for 1/5/2010 for instance. I would need to get record 5 for checkbox 3 as opposed to record 4 for checkbox 3. Using your first query I would incorrectly see that checkbox 3 was selected on 1/5/2010. Understand? Your third code block will get the job done but I'm hoping there is a less brute force method to do it i.e. pure LINQ way.

Comment: Then just remove the where clause and group by checkboxid, then you can order the sets for each checkboxid however you want and see each entry